# How to add "config.include FactoryBot::Syntax::Methods" to rspec config block in spec_helper.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot, rspec-rails

If I add:

```
config.include FactoryBot::Syntax::Methods
```

under

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
```

and run rspec, I see this error:

> /Users/perry_mac/rails_projects/mymri/spec/spec_helper.rb:21:in `block
>   in ': uninitialized constant FactoryBot (NameError)

my gemfile.lock can be seen in [this pastebin](http://pastebin.com/k6pb7f2T)
my gemfile can be seen in [this pastebin](http://pastebin.com/XV53rDR3)

If I omit the Rspec.configure statement, my tests all run fine.  I'd like to make use of the abbreviated syntax, but am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Note: FactoryBot was previously called FactoryGirl

Comment: `gem 'factory_girl_rails'` does the gem present in Gemfile ?

Comment: yes, for both :development and :test environments.

Comment: and this line? `require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)`

Comment: added a link to pastebin of my gemfile.

Comment: require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)    appears in rails_helper.rb

Comment: you can try my installation for rspec by my `gem teleporter` and then run `rails g initial:rspec_base` but commit your changes before running. Source code here: https://github.com/itsNikolay/teleporter

Comment: Uh, what?  Am not familiar with the teleporter gem.

Comment: This is just generators for installation gems you can check it mannually https://github.com/itsNikolay/teleporter/blob/master/lib/generators/initial/rspec_base.rb

Comment: I appreciate the offer, but I am hoping to find a more specific answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Got it.

This [link](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md) showed me the way.

The required addition should be made in `spec/support/factory_bot.rb` and it should look like this:

```
# RSpec
# spec/support/factory_bot.rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include FactoryBot::Syntax::Methods
end
```

Note: FactoryBot was previously called FactoryGirl

Answer (score 11):

You must add this string in file 'spec/**RAILS**_helper.rb' not in 'spec_helper.rb'

Answer (score 11):

Also make sure to `require 'factory_bot'` in `spec/support/factory_bot.rb`

That's what ended up being the issue for me.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure to include `require 'support/factory_girl'` in `spec/rails_helper.rb` *after* `require 'rspec/rails'`.

I was getting this error after putting it right after `require 'spec_helper'`.

Answer (score 3):

This answer is compiled and tested from previous comments and [factory_bot](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#rspec).

1. Create `spec/support/factory_bot.rb` file.
2. Paste inside `spec/support/factory_bot.rb` file:

```ruby
require 'factory_bot'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include FactoryBot::Syntax::Methods
end
```

3. Add `require 'support/factory_bot.rb'` in `spec/rails_helper.rb` file or uncomment the following line in your `rails_helper.rb`:

```ruby
Dir[Rails.root.join('spec', 'support', '**', '*.rb')].sort.each { |f| require f }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's worth mentioning here that, going forward, if using FactoryGirl, you will receive a deprecation message:

```
The factory_girl gem has been deprecated and has been replaced by factory_bot. Please switch to factory_bot as soon as possible.
```

Just a note for developers in the future that are trying to use FactoryGirl.