# Rails / Factory Girl: Uninitialized constant FactoryGirl (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot, rspec-rails

I installed the `factory_girl` gem, and when I run my tests I get an error:

> `block in ': uninitialized constant FactoryGirl (NameError)

This is my `spec_helper.rb`

```ruby
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end
  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end
end
```

How can it be fixed?

Comment: Can you paste any relevant entries from your `Gemfile`? Is that your full `spec_helper.rb`? Is this a Rails project?

Comment: thank you Joe, I was solved problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This must be your answer.

*The required addition should be made in spec/support/factory_girl.rb*

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25649064/1503970

Answer (score 4):

In `spec/spec_helper.rb`, try adding

```ruby
FactoryGirl.find_definitions
```

under

```ruby
require 'factory_girl_rails'
```

or make sure you follow [factory_bot's Getting Started](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/factory_bot/file/GETTING_STARTED.md) guide.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just putting this here for anyone clumsy like me. Everything was fine, but I was calling `FactoryGirl` in one place, when I only have `FactoryBot` installed. Newbie error. Hope it might help.